# Disable Bluetooth Tile in Quick Settings Panel

Tags: android, android-source, android-bluetooth, android-app-quick-setting

I want to disable Bluetooth tile from the quick settings panel. I am using android 9 and I want to do it on a system app. So if there are some changes to be made in source, I would be happy to know it.

I have found many solutions telling how to add a new custom tile via TileService, but I need to disable tiles that are already present (like Bluetooth tile).

Note: I do not want the feature itself to be disabled, i.e. the user would be able to enable disable feature from the settings app itself. I just want to disable the qs tile.

Comment: There is a data structure maintaining `tiles`. Did you try to disable `Bluetooth` tile based on index or name in that data structure i.e. Array?

Comment: @Kushal No. I do not know how to disable it. I can remove the tile from Settings.Secure, but I can't disable it. Can you please explain in detail.

Comment: Do you want to disable the tile or remove it?

Comment: @frogatto Disable it.

Comment: @AbdullahRiaz Turning off the Bluetooth by default or merely disable its tile forever?

Comment: Only Disable the tile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searched a bit on cs.android.com and this seems to be the relevant class.

[frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/tiles/BluetoothTile.java](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/tiles/BluetoothTile.java?q=BluetoothTile&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject)

From there you can handle click ( or not handle it actually), or show a "disabled" icon etc.

If you want to "remove" it, then [frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/tileimpl/QSFactoryImpl.java](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/tileimpl/QSFactoryImpl.java;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=134) seems to be the class that adds them. It reads from  [Settings.Secure.QS_TILES](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/customize/TileQueryHelper.java;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=85)

Comment: I have been through these classes. It seems, changing the source is the only solution to disable the tile. 
If there were some settings like sysui_qs_tiles in Settings.Secure, it would have been a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, modifying BluetoothTile itself looks like the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/tileimpl/QSFactoryImpl.java

yes, This file we can edit and remove unwanted tiles.